# How to animate through li elements with a small delay in between

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, html-lists

I would like each li element to move across the screen, one after the other, with a small delay between each one.

The animation of each li element should begin before the previous element has finished animating.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$("#navright ul li:nth-child(1)").animate({marginLeft:'115px'},500).delay(150);
$("#navright ul li:nth-child(2)").animate({marginLeft:'115px'},500).delay(150);    
$("#navright ul li:nth-child(3)").animate({marginLeft:'115px'},500).delay(150);
$("#navright ul li:nth-child(4)").animate({marginLeft:'115px'},500);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Are you talking about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xcvc2uwm/

Comment: That's it. Perfect. Please post so I can mark it as the right answer...

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are looking for is a graduated delay.  This is better accomplished with a loop (my example will use jQuery's `.each()` method).  The general concept is to increase the delay in a controlled way.  My comment above works for the current 4 but is generally not a good approach from a scaling point of view.  It creates an almost exponential increase overtime.  My example below takes the total delay plus two thirds of that initial delay as the factor by which the delay increases over time.  The only real problem with your original code is that you need the call to `.delay()` to occur before the `.animate()` call.  Below is my updated example.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xcvc2uwm/1/

```js
var d = 150, factor = d / 3 * 2; // increment delay by two thirds original delay
$("#navright ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).delay(d = d + factor).animate({marginLeft:'115px'},500);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navright">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Hopefully this helps.